# Checking strings match certain format

Tags: java

How would I go about checking a string to make sure the first characters are letters and the rest are numeric?

Example of the format I am checking for

```
ZA825
FD8821
TT42212333
```

It doesn't matter the length as long as **the first 2 are letters and the rest are numeric**.

Comment: Start learning [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Comment: `str.matches("[A-Z]{2}\\d*")`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to implement this is through regular expressions. Java does this through the classes `Pattern`, found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and `Matcher`, found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

```
public bool matches(String s) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]{2}\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    return m.matches();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

To simply verify that a string matches a pattern like the one described:

```
//                             two letters
//                              /      \
boolean valid = string.matches("[A-Z]{2}\\d+");
//                                      \  /
//                               one or more digits
```

If you must do this check many times or have further needs (e.g. extracting substrings), use the [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class.